# Why is jquery not allowing ascii characters to display in html?

Tags: jquery, html, ascii

I am using a jquery character counter and integrating it with my form helpers in Codeigniter.I've got everything working as it should, however when I'm using this script, parentheses are not showing up. I typed them in and used the ascii codes, and they only show up when I take off the script.

Any idea what this maybe?

thanks in advance.

javascript:

```
<script>
    function updateCountdown_mylife() {
        var remaining = 1340 - jQuery('.message_mylife').val().length;
        jQuery('#mylife').text(remaining + ' characters remaining.');
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        updateCountdown_mylife();
        $('.message_mylife').change(updateCountdown_mylife);
        $('.message_mylife').keyup(updateCountdown_mylife);
    });

    function updateCountdown_occupation() {
        var remaining = 200 - jQuery('.message_occupation').val().length;
        jQuery('#occupation').text(remaining + ' characters remaining.');
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        updateCountdown_occupation();
        $('.message_occupation').change(updateCountdown_occupation);
        $('.message_occupation').keyup(updateCountdown_occupation);
    });
    </script>
```

html:

```
My Life <br /><span class="title_sub_text">Tell us a about yourself</span> <span class="edit_sub_text" id="mylife">&#40;1350 character limit&#41;</span>
```

textarea:

```
<div class="edit_text_area">        
            <?php 

            if(empty($user['mylife']))
            {
                $data = array('name' => 'mylife', 'class' => 'message_mylife');
                echo form_textarea($data);
            }
            else
            {
                $data = array('name' => 'mylife', 'class' => 'message_mylife');
                echo form_textarea($data, $user['mylife']);
            }


            ?>
        </div>
```

thans in advance

Comment: I don't see an issue - please check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GjRYL/  - You may modify the same to replicate the issue

Comment: @VinayC The issue is on the link to that fiddle. It should print (1350 character limit) not 1350 character limit

Comment: Please see my answer if that is what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are saying then the parenthesis are not showing up because you are overwriting the span text and not putting the parenthesis there while over-writing. For example, shouldn't the relevant code in `updateCountdown_mylife` be modified as

```
jQuery('#mylife').text('(' + remaining + ' characters remaining)');
```

Note the parenthesis included within. Also to display `(1350 character limit)` at start-up, just comment out `updateCountdown_mylife` call in start-up code i.e.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // updateCountdown_mylife(); // this line would modify span text at start-up
        $('.message_mylife').change(updateCountdown_mylife);
```

I have modified JS fiddle with these changes - check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GjRYL/1/): http://jsfiddle.net/GjRYL/1/ - hopefully, this is what you are after.